# Handling assets with webpack within ReactJs application

Tags: reactjs, image, typescript, webpack, assets

I need to load an image in my React component :

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/boot.tsx' },
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader?minimize' }) },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,  loader: 'file-loader' },
                { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
                { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" } 
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CheckerPlugin(),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css')
        ])
    }];
};
```

In the component, I tried to load the image like this :

```
  import Logo from '../css/images/logo.png';
```

but it did not work !

How can I edit the configure the webpack to handle the assets espacially images?

Thanks,

Comment: if it is locally stored by don't you directly show img by giving path in `src`

Comment: The problem is that the image is not found , even I try `<img src="../css/images/backhome.png" />` for example

Comment: no try using `require` like <img src={require("../css/images/backhome.png")} />

Comment: @Revansiddh it works thanks, can u please post your comment as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, I considering your image file is locally stored. Did you created reactjs app using `created-react-app` or `ejected` the app.

`import Logo from '../css/images/logo.png'`

and use like `<img src={Logo} className="blue"/>`

or `<img src={require('../css/images/logo.png')} className="blue"/>`